# how can I create facebook style single line validations i ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, validation

I like facebook style  single line validations so I wrote this code:

```
def fields_filled_in?
  if first_name.blank? || last_name.blank? || email.blank?
    self.errors[:base] << "Please fill in all fields"
  else
    if email !~ /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
      self.errors[:base] << "Enter a valid email address"
    else
      if((first_name.length < 2 || last_name.length < 2) ||(first_name.length > 32 || last_name.length > 32))
        self.errors[:base] << "Enter valid full name" 
      else
        if password.blank?
          self.errors[:base] << "Enter a password"
        else
          if password.length < 6
            self.errors[:base] << "Password must be at least 6 character"
          end    
        end            
      end    
    end        
  end      
end
```

it works only, it's missing the email uniqueness and doesn't look like rails code.

Comment: Have you tried the [ClientSideValidation gem](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations)? There's also a [RailsCasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations) about it.

Comment: Good screencasts thank you. I am learning so trying to find out how experts do it.